# Are there any open source filesystems for Windows that support encryption?

Tags: windows, filesystems, nfs, ext3

I know that NTFS supports encryption but otherwise is closed source. Likewise, I am aware of add-ins such as truecrypt but I am interested in encryption being built-in vs being bolted on.

Comment: Are there any open source file systems for Windows even without encryption (ones that aren't 'proof of concept' or toys)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that encryption is often not done at the filesystem level.  It's done at the block level, where sectors are actually read/written to disk.  This allows one to use any filesystem with the encryption, as the filesystem sits on top of the encryption layer.

Answer (score 2):

No.

There's [Bitlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitlocker), but it's implementation is closed source.  Everything else not manufactured by Microsoft will, by definition, be "bolted on".  Microsoft doesn't provide any open source filesystems in their OSes, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Any specific use cases?

TrueCrypt [supports full volume encryption](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=system-encryption), with a boot password.  I have been unable to confirm this, but I believe that BitLocker also requires a password at boot.  TrueCrypt is the only option I've been able to find, and it is relatively mature.  Full disk encryption with TrueCrypt would be transparent - I'm not sure what you mean by "bolted-on", but I assume you mean not having to mount an encrypted volume each time you log in.

Edit: Unfortunately there is no version of FUSE for Windows. There are the [Dokan libraries](http://code.google.com/p/dokan/), but they're not widely used AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use TrueCrypt, but [PGP](http://www.pgp.com/products/wholediskencryption/) is excellent too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check OS edition of our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/), which does what you need. Source code is available, although not free.